# Error while putting string into stack C++

Tags: c++, stack

I have a big problem with "program language" called C++.
I wanted to print the stack of strings.

```
void show(stack<string> stos) {
  while (!stos.empty()) {
    cout << stos.pop() << endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`pop()` only removes the top element from the stack and throws it away. It returns `void` (nothing) and you can't print that with `cout`, obviously. You need:

```
void show(stack<string> stos)
{
    while(!stos.empty()) {
        cout << stos.top() << endl;
        stos.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pop` doesn't return the value removed.  You have to first access `top()` to get the value, then call `pop()` to get rid of it.